# How to use the dev and prod environment with Azure AD for authentication used by ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, webforms

I'm working on an old ASP.NET webforms/MVC app and I'm trying to use Azure AD authentication method. It was done with the prod server, but when I want to use localhost or dev server, I added their URL also on the application under "Redirect URIs" in Azure Portal configuration.

The problem is in that case when I do that: each time I open the Prod link I get redirected to the new link that I added (localhost or dev)

I don't have a lot of experience with Azure AD, I just need to know how can I the dev and localhost servers with the prod (which is working fine on my side).

Can you please assist with this? Thank you in advance

Statup file code:

```cs
Partial Public Class Startup

 Private Shared clientId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:ClientId")
    Private Shared appKey As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:ClientSecret")
    Private Shared aadInstance As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:AADInstance")
    Private Shared tenantId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:TenantId")
    Private Shared postLogoutRedirectUri As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri")

    Public Shared ReadOnly Authority As String = aadInstance + tenantId

    ' This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
    Private graphResourceId As String = "https://graph.windows.net/"

    Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
        Dim db As New ApplicationDbContext()

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
        app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver()
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())

        ' If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions() With {
                .ClientId = clientId,
                .Authority = Authority,
                .PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications() With {
                .AuthorizationCodeReceived = Function(context)
                                                 Dim code = context.Code
                                                 Dim credential As New ClientCredential(clientId, appKey)
                                                 Dim signedInUserID As String = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
                                                 Dim authContext As New AuthenticationContext(Authority, New ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID))
                                                 Return authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, New Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId)

                                             End Function
                }
            })
    End Sub
End Class
```

Web.Config:

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="test" />
<add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
<add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="test" />
<add key="ida:Domain" value="test.com" />
<add key="ida:TenantId" value="test" />
<add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="ProductionUrl" />
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```

***Redirect URIs in Azure AD***

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Share the configuration file in text format.Also share your startup code for authentication.

Comment: What is the .net framework version of your app?

Comment: The .net framework version is: 4.7.2

Comment: In `Web.config` file change the `PostLogoutRedirectUri` to localhost Url.And add redirectURI of both local host and deployed app in Azure AD.

Comment: Can you please share your RedirectURI screen cap.

Comment: Thanks for you reply but I keep having the same issue, When I open the prod URL I'm redirected to localhost now. my goal is to use prod and dev and localhost at the same time instead of replacing PostLogoutRedirectUri in the web.config and the Redirect URIs in Azure AD one by one each time.

Comment: Your code seems to be VB.Net. Are you using VB.Net?

Comment: Yes I'm using VB.Net now.

Comment: Even Iam facing the same issue.I have even tried with multiple configuration files based on environment.The issue seems to be only with the RedirectURI in AD.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply ! so what's the alternative I have an app configured with Azure AD using prod and it works fine, but I can't use localhost or the dev server to test unless I add their URLs in Azure AD Redirect URIs,  and in that case when someone use the prod URL I he get redirected to one of these URLs !

Comment: Iam looking for an alternative.. Will let you once Iam able to solve it.

Comment: Great ! I appreciate you help.

Comment: AFAIK,this is the existing behavior of the RedirectURI.App will pick the URI which is on top of the Redirect URI List.Trying with mutiple configuration files has not helped.

Comment: thanks again, is there a way to do that using two separate Apps under Azure Ad for both production and localhost ?

Comment: AFAIK,For now the only option in my mind is to have 2 app registrations.One for Local and other for Production.While pushing the app you can change the client id and re-deploy to production.

Comment: thanks again, is there a way to do that using two separate application registrations under Azure Ad for both production and localhost ?

Comment: Will try from my end , If that is working will post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD can have multiple [redirect URI's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/reply-url#maximum-number-of-redirect-uris).

As an alternative approach

***Check the below work around to have two App Registrations for both Dev and Prod App.***

- Create 2 App Registrations, 1 for Production and the other for Development.

[image]

- Except `Client ID` other credentials like `TenantID`,`AADInstance` and `Domain` will be same for both the registered apps in AD.
- Set the `Redirect URI's` for both the apps in AD.

***Production***

```cs
https://azuread28nov.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc
```

***Localhost:***

```cs
https://localhost:44318/signin-oidc
```

- In VS,First Configure the Web App with Production Credentials.
- In `web.config` file, change the ClientID to the Production (ADProduction)and deploy the app to `Azure App Service`.
- To continue to work in local, change the ClientID to the Development (ADLocalhost).

***Output:***
***Development:***

[image]
***Production:***

[image]

Comment: Hi Harshitha, sorry for the delay to confirm if the answer solved my problem I was informed today that the new app was added under Azure Portal, so I tested with your solution with the same config expect for ClientID and secretID so I had to change them each time when I want to change the server but your solution solved my issue thank you !